# Showing that $ \# \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} ^2 | a^2 + b^2=n \} = 4(e_1+1)...(e_r +1 ) $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

Let $$n= 2^a p_1^{e_1}...p_r^{e_r}q_1^{f_1}...q_s^{f_s} $$ be
the prime factorization of $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, where $ p_1,\ldots,p_r $ are the primes leaving a residue of $1\bmod{4}$, $q_1,...,q_s$ are the ones leaving a residue of $3$, and $f_1,...,f_s $ are even numbers.

How can I show that 
 $$ \# \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} ^2 | a^2 + b^2=n \} = 4(e_1+1)...(e_r +1 ) ?$$

Any help is appreciated.
__
_Edit

I try to get an example for this to understand it more..the answere in the linked duplikate is not very clear to me.
lets take $ 65$

$65= 5* 13 $

$65=(1* 3+2*2)^2+(2*3-1*2)^2  $

I can't find a representation for the $4(e_1 +1)..(e_r+1) $
what is $e$ in this case?

Comment: By rest of 1 and 3, do you mean 1 and 3 mod 4, respectively?

Comment: i think so..im sorry, i am trying to understand this statement :D